# vim :AnsiEsc - how to have them on by default?

Tags: vim, ansi-escape

I have log files (let say with the extension *.smt2) with colored log entries, where colors are defined by ansi escape codes. I installed the vim plugin based on [AnsiEsc.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302).

Now when I open my vim editor I need to type :AnsiEsc.
How can I add :AnsiEsc to my .vimrc to be in my default view?

Answer (score 6):

Your autocmd will only work for the first file that is passed as a command-line argument, as the `:AnsiEsc` command only applies to the current buffer. It will miss files opened via `:edit` or `:split`. Better use the `BufRead` event:

```
autocmd BufRead * AnsiEsc
```

Also, I wonder whether you only use Vim to view log files (that would be a pity)? The `:AnsiEsc` command may interfere with editing other kind of files.

The usual solution for that is defining a *custom filetype*, e.g. `log`. You can then enable the plugin for those files via the following script in `~/.vim/ftplugin/log.vim`:

```
" Only do this when not done yet for this buffer
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
    finish
endif
AnsiEsc
```

(You also need to have `:filetype plugin on` in your .vimrc.)

To open a log file, you have to specify the filetype: `vim "+setf log" logfile`, or later inside Vim via `:setf log`. Of course, if the logfile names follow a pattern or have a certain common string inside, you can be fancy and write a *filetype detection*; see `:help new-filetype`. Or you write a shell alias, e.g. `alias vimlog='vim +setf\ log'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if the files are with the specific extension, such as *.smt2.

I only need the files with this extension to be shown with :AnsiEsc

Comment: That would be exactly the case for the second part of my answer - a custom filetype. To detect those files as type `log` (you can adapt that), put `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.smt2 set filetype=log` into `~/.vim/ftdetect/log.vim`. Cp. `:help new-filetype` for details.