# Problem with text editors in macOS for Diff of two files with ANSI escape codes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, sublimetext3, ansi-escape

I have two log files in macOS where colors are defined by `ANSI Escape codes` and want to compare them.  Having ANSI escape codes in plain text makes it really annoying to read the diff. I am looking for either (i) **removing** the ANSI escape codes from files, or (ii) **bringing back** the colour highlighting to the log files. Any recommendations?

I tried some text edirors in Mac but no success:

1. **Sublime text**.  Installed [ANSIescape](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ANSIescape) using 'Sublime Package Control'. It's nice for displaying ANSI code with color for a single file, but it does not work for comparing two files. Because the diff are displayed in two separate files, not side-by-side.
2. **Visual studio code**. It has nice side-by-side comparison by the command `code --diff file1 file2`, but I failed to find any ANSI escape codes *plugins for VS code*.
3. **Vim**.  I failed to install the plugin based on [AnsiEsc.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302).
   Once I had installed it in other system, but the problem was when you open the vim editor every time you need to type :AnsiEsc, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475460/vim-ansiesc-how-to-have-them-on-by-default). The error I get in installing the plugin is:

   ```
   *vimball*** (vimball#Decompress) gunzip may have failed with <~/AnsiEsc.vba.gz>
           Press <cr> to continue

    ***vimball*** Source this file to extract it! (:so %)
    Error detected while processing SourceCmd Auto commands for "*.vba.gz":
    E484: Can't open file ~/AnsiEsc.vba
   ```